# Is it possible to unpack a tuple in Python without creating unwanted variables?

Tags: python, tuples, iterable-unpacking

Is there a way to write the following function so that my IDE doesn't complain that *column* is an unused variable?

```
def get_selected_index(self):
    (path, column) = self._tree_view.get_cursor()
    return path[0]
```

In this case I don't care about the second item in the tuple and just want to discard the reference to it when it is unpacked.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In Python the `_` is often used as an ignored placeholder.

```
(path, _) = self._treeView.get_cursor()
```

You could also avoid unpacking as a tuple is indexable.

```
def get_selected_index(self):
    return self._treeView.get_cursor()[0][0]
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `_` is not any kind of syntactic magic, but a convention (of course, it's a convention recognised by IDEs and pylint, and Python conventions are pretty strong...)

Comment: Python would be nothing without conventions!

Comment: Is this convention documented?

Comment: @fredley - I'm not disputing that at all :) but still worth mentioning. @Nathan - ...maybe?

Comment: The same is often used in Lua; I suspect it's a common theme in languages that support this sort of unpacking.

Comment: It is common in OCaml and Haskell.

Comment: And is also common in Prolog: in fact it is a little more than a convention, it is an anonymous variable (and can be repeated, without it meaning the same value) in a matching statement. IIRC Erlang handles it similarly.

Comment: @Gaius: I believe in Haskell it explicitly means "discard this value"; in Python `_` is still an assigned variable that you could in theory use just like any other variable.

Comment: The python command line interpreter "magically" assigns _ to the result of the last computation so if you run something but forget to store the return value, it will be captured for you in the `_` variable. It's a useful thing while doing interactive work. In the above case, I'd probably do indexing rather than unpacking though.

Comment: The parentheses in the first code snippet are unnecessary, aren't they?

Comment: @mattb: They are optional.

Comment: What if your tuple has three or more elements? I do this all the time, especially in test code that creates dummy objects.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care about the second item, why not just extract the first one:

```
def get_selected_index(self):
    path = self._treeView.get_cursor()[0]
    return path[0]
```

Comment: Note that the return should now be `return path`, not `return path[0]`

Comment: This is weaker, because it removes the assertion that there are exactly two items.

Comment: @Michael Mior: I've rolled back your edit: Based on the original question, it should still be `path[0]` (`path` seems to be a sequence itself)

Comment: I'd argue that this is less explicit as the _ placeholder convention. There's potential ambiguity in the order of operations, is it: `(path = self._treeView.get_cursor())[0]` or `path = (self._treeView.get_cursor()[0])`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. The accepted answer with `_` convention still unpacks, just to a placeholder variable.

You can avoid this via [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import islice

values = (i for i in range(2))

res = next(islice(values, 1, None))  # 1
```

This will give the same `res` as below:

```
_, res = values
```

The solution, as demonstrated above, works when `values` is an iterable that is not an indexable collection such as `list` or `tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

it looks pretty, I don't know if a good performance.

```
a = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
x, y = a[0:2]
```